# how to access oracle 10g OLAP programmatically in a web application

Tags: web-applications, oracle10g, olap

Oracle provided BI Beans libraries which allows a web application to access Oracle OLAP. It seems that there are no new version of BI beans and that it is no more supported by Oracle.

Given above, how can we access Oracle 10g/11g OLAP in java/jsp programs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The download is still available, and they are still supported, although perhaps not as much as you'd like. See [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/bbi-beans/overview/oraclebibeanssod2008-129560.pdf) document, which also details alternatives. It's available from Oracle's BI Beans page:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/bbi-beans/overview/index.html

From my quick read of that document, it appears that Oracle's ADF components are the way to go. It also looks like BI Beans will still be covered by Oracle Fusion Middleware Extended Support until the end of 2011, and by Sustaining Support indefinitely.